# handling of 2 signals at aproximately the same time

Tags: c, linux, signals

In Linux 2.6, I would like my process to catch both SIGHUP and SIGTERM in order to exit orderly.

When the node shuts down, logs show that it will handle either SIGHUP (the parent process receives SIGTERM) or SIGTERM first.

My question is: is there a possibility that the handlers for these signals are called concurrently? or the kernel triggers one after the other?

Comment: Regarding first question, I think you can't do that. But regarding second question, you can do a raise(SIGTERM) in handler for SIGHUP and viceversa. Of course, you should check if you are not coming the the other handler.

Comment: A clarification: the process receives both SIGHUP and SIGTERM on shutdown because they receive the SIGTERM due to shutdown and because the parent process does also and dies.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your code architecture you could enforce synchronous reading of signals preventing any concurrency issues. You could use signalfd and then read from that fd whenever you want to check on any outstanding signals. If you *need* them to behave in their asynchronous default with a signal handler I think you have to be prepared for your signal handler to be potentially interrupted.

[man signalfd](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/signalfd.2.html)

Answer (score 0):

In Asynchronous signals to a process, the Linux kernel send signals with a system call to target process structure and when context of the process is switched to RUN state, signals are handled by root thread and block signals on all other threads. Since the stack space is different for each thread each signal can be handled at a time(Correct if am wrong).

Comment: @AndresVelascoGarcia If it is process, shouldn't the signal handlers are executed sequentially reading each signal form the kernel. Correct me if wrong.